# jQuery text-highlight menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a Medium style text-highlight menu as shown below which works when you highlight a piece of text in body. I got this working fine in the first three paragraphs. However, when you scroll down and select the text the menu does not show at the right place but in the very top of the page. Appreciate if someone could help in this matter.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hLm9tvr1/1/)

[image]

HTML

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</p>

<div id="highlight_menu" style="display:none;"> 
  
  <ul class="social-share">
    <li>Link 1</li>
    <li>Link 2</li>
    <li>Link 3</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="caret">
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(function(){
  var menu = $('#highlight_menu');
  
  $(document.body).on('mouseup', function (evt) {
    var s = document.getSelection(),
      r = s.getRangeAt(0);
    if (r && s.toString()) {
      var p = r.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (p.left || p.top) {
        menu.css({
          left: (p.left + (p.width / 2)) - (menu.width() / 2),
          top: (p.top - menu.height() - 10),
          display: 'block',
          opacity: 0
      })
      .animate({
        opacity:1
      }, 300);
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        menu.addClass('highlight_menu_animate');
      }, 10);
      return;
    }
    }
    menu.animate({ opacity:0 }, function () {
      menu.hide().removeClass('highlight_menu_animate');
  });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getBoundingClientRect() gets values with respect to the window(only the current visible portion of the page), not the document(whole page).
Hence, it also takes scrolling into account when calculating its values.

Update this line:

```
top: ((p.top + window.scrollY) - menu.height() - 10),
```